# The second HDD constantly awaking on Win10

Tags: hard-drive, power

I have an ASUS Vivobook x510, running Windows 10 [build 18363.1500], and am looking for advice on how to make a WD Blue 2TB secondary HDD sleep when I'm not using it (I mainly use a small system SSD), as it is constantly waking every 10min even though I'm not accessing it:

- I set up the HDD to sleep after 2min of idle in a power plan, but it awakes after ~10 min
- I've tried RevoSleep and disabling the low disk notification, but it did not solve the problem

Any advice? Why is an Intel graphics process, `explorer`, and `svchost` (what is that?) accessing it? 
 [image: Proc monitor for that disk]

UPDATE:
So I eventually figure out that disabling the next services somehow helped solve my problem:

- Storage Service
- Intel hd graphic controll panel services

Although after disabling Storage Service, the advanced power management setting for HDD stopped work, so it isn't going to sleep after a certain interval by itself. But it is still possible to put HDD into sleep with revoSleep, and it is no more awake until I access it.

I think that disabling Storage Service isn't the best solution and there might be some setting or other option to solve this problem. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: You don't need intel graphics process.  Explorer is .. well .. everything that makes the desktop, file manager and taskbar work and svchost is a plethora of assorted services.  Start by disabling the intel junk.  Make sure the drive isn't referenced in your path statement and narrow down what thread within svchost by examining exactly what it is trying to do on that drive.  Oh! NICE WORK using the system internals process monitor!!

Comment: That graphic is too small for me to see.  It might be helpful to post a link to a larger one.

Comment: Señor CMasMas, thanks! It seems that disabling intel graphics and storage service helped me. Although there is still some request in the process monitor, the drive isn't awake.

Comment: You are welcome.  I am glad this helped.